# How to add a row style dynamically ? - Ag-grid

Tags: ag-grid

I want to change the style of a row dynamically in ag-grid. What I'm trying to achieve is to change the background color of my ag-grid row if the row has been edited by the user.

```
cellValueChanged(event) {
  //Add it only if the old value has changed
  if (event.oldValue != event.newValue) {
     // This will replace with latest edited value if it has been edited already
     this.edittedRows[event.rowIndex.toString()] = event.data;
  }
}
```

I'm keeping track of the edited row by listening to `cellValueChanged` event. I need to change the row style here.
I've looked into ag-grid documentation and found how to add row styles, row classes and row class rules but I could't find a way to add a style to a row dynamically when the user has changed something on it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

By using `redrawRows` I was able to achieve this.

First I added `rowClassRules` for my grid options like below

```
private initGrid() {
   this.gridOptions.rowClassRules = {
      'modified' : this.isEditedRow()
   };
}

private isEditedRow() {
   return (params) => {
      return params.data.edited;
   }
}
```

`modified` is my css class which has all the styles for an edited row.

Then in my row data I'm adding a new property `edited`.
 And changed the `cellValueChanged` as below,

```
cellValueChanged(event) {
  //Add it only if the old value has changed
  if (event.oldValue != event.newValue) {
     // This will replace with latest edited value if it has been edited already

     // Setting edited flag to change the background
     event.data.edited = true;
     this.edittedRows[event.rowIndex.toString()] = event.data;
     let row = this.gridApi.getDisplayedRowAtIndex(event.rowIndex);
     this.gridApi.redrawRows({ rowNodes: [row] });
  }

}
```

Find the documentation for redrawRows [here](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-refresh/#redraw-rows).

Answer (score 0):

Add below line in your CellValueChanged Function:

> gridOptions.rowStyle = {background: 'coral'};

```
cellValueChanged(event) {
  //Add it only if the old value has changed
  if (event.oldValue != event.newValue) {
     // This will replace with latest edited value if it has been edited already
     this.edittedRows[event.rowIndex.toString()] = event.data;
     gridOptions.rowStyle = {background: 'coral'};
  }
}
```

> Plunker - https://plnkr.co/edit/i1K3YXpGGgNEOU2JjZCf?p=preview

Comment: It's working from the second edit. In your plunkr example if I edit something initially it won't change the style, but from the second edit it does.

Comment: Changing the gridOption's rowStyle will affect for the whole grid. For all the rows adding after the change will get this style even if those aren't edited. And also changing it won't affect the initially edited row but for the rows edited next.

Comment: @Senal - what do you want? dont you want the rows to be of different style after the cellls are edited? this code just puts background color to the edited rows.

Comment: yes I want the rows to be of different style after the cells are edited. From `gridOptions.rowStyle = {background: 'coral'};` we are changing the whole grid's rowStyle after the first `cellValueChanged` event so it will add this style for edited rows and for all the newly created rows as well. I want to add a style just to the row I have edited.